# Selecionar Row no **DataGridView** com o botão direito

Tags: c#, datagridview

desde de já agradeço o tempo de vocês :D

Tenho um **dataGridView** preenchido por um **DataTable**

Quero selecionar(fullRowSelect) ele apenas quando clicar com o botão direito e não com o esquerdo.

Alguém ajuda?

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma forma "bonita" de o fazer, mas há sempre algo a tentar:

```
dataGridView1.MouseClick += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hitTest = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        dataGridView1.Rows[hitTest.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
};
```

Com esta solução há algum *flickering*, mas acho que consegue o que pretende.

Existem outras soluções, mas vão todas dar praticamente ao mesmo.

Comment: A sim, funcionou, você sabe me dizer como executar essa ação antes de um **ContexMenuStrip** ser exibido?

Comment: Aí teria que alterar o funcionamento de abertura do `ContextMenu`. Não será melhor colocar uma nova questão? E, se possível, colocar código, senão vai ter a sua questão fechada :)

Comment: Man, eu não entendo, como vou colocar código de algo que não sei fazer, se fosse algo do tipo: "Onde está o erro" ou Melhor forma de chegar a tal solução, ai sim, mas não é o caso, o que você quer de código, não entendo, qual parte do código do projeto você quer e no que isso ajuda?

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor:
Eu tenho um **DataGridView** chamado **DgvLocacao**, um **ContexMenuStrip** chamado **cmsLocacao**.

Quando eu clicar com o botão direito em uma linha do **DgvLocacao** ela fica selecionada(E não com o esquerdo como é o natural do controle)
Mas gostaria que fosse possível selecionar antes e após isso aparecer o **CmsLocacao**